# How to require/provide a package name with the value of `user-login-name`, without hard coding it?

Tags: package, require

I am trying to load package depending on a user's login name
For example:

If a user's login name is "user_foo", I would like to `(require 'user_foo)`. I don't want to hard code the user's login name.

I tried:

```
(require user_login_name)
```

I got `wrong type argument: symbolp, "user_foo"
What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(require (intern user-login-name))
```

`require` needs a symbol as its argument, the value of `user-log-name` is a string, `intern` takes a string and returns a symbol.